# I want sum sum all the QTY which have same Model number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

SL is the primary key.
Table name -> impo
I want to sum all the QTY which have same Model number.(Here add 40+35 because of INDO666)

I tried this:

```
SELECT i.Model_num, i.QTY 
FROM impo AS i 
    JOIN (SELECT Model_num, SUM(QTY) AS t_qty 
            FROM impo 
            GROUP BY Model_num ) 
    AS s ON i.Model_num = s.Model_num
```

Comment: Okay. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried this:  SELECT i.Model_num, i.QTY
          FROM impo AS i
          JOIN (SELECT Model_num, SUM(QTY) AS t_qty
           FROM impo
           GROUP BY Model_num
           ) AS s ON i.Model_num = s.Model_num

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you have an extra `join`.  The subquery seems to do what you want:

```
SELECT Model_num, SUM(QTY) AS t_qty 
FROM impo 
GROUP BY Model_num ;
```

Comment: I don't think OP understands either.